# Azure Single Sign-On using SAML 2.0 Protocol and ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I want to implement Azure AD Single Sign-On using SAML 2.0 Protocol and ASP.NET C#.

According to the below documentation we have to make a 'AuthnRequest' with certain parameters and process the 'Response'.

Possible to use any particualr assembly to process the saml request and response? [like owin or onelogin]

It will be really helpful, if someone can provide me a sample application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no official SDK for the same from MS but you can refer below link for implementation:

```
 https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html
 https://github.com/onelogin
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any sample with onelogin or owin?

Comment: Can you check in the github link i posted above in my answer. It has many samples for the same.

Comment: Do let me know if you have any issues around that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are asking for some assembly/component which would process the SAML response.

I have coded a similar setup, based on the [.NET Oracle OpenSSO fedlet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/confignetsp.htm), which even is closed source as-of-now you can find some some [repos containing a fork](https://github.com/ThinkSmart/Fedlet) for the original open source code.

These solutions will require further work on your side, but it's a good start point.

Hope this help you and feel free to ask more specific questions.